# Windows Phone 7 Development Books to Suggest !

Tags: windows-phone-7

Which books would you suggest about Windows Phone 7 Development ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of current and upcoming books for Windows Phone 7 development has been compiled here for reference.

[Recommended books for learning to program Windows Phone Apps?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/73024085-e1e3-4467-bc6d-f169e7de88b9)

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? (I'm assuming you are meaning Windows Phone 7 Series?)

http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/

Comment: you ara assuming correctly :)

Comment: The complete Charles Petzold eBook is now available as a free download (also with the code samples): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx